# How to activate CSS panel within HTML panel in a console of Firebug of Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firebug

Please see the two pictures below.

1) Chrome OK. I have CSS panel in HTML panel.

[image]

**2) Firebug ISSUE**. There is no CSS panel in HTML panel. How to make in appear?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you click the arrow icon in the top-right of the Firebug window, it should show the Style options for you:

[image: Firebug icon]

[image: Firebug with style open]

**Edit:**

In response to your question below, you can move the sidebar between the right and bottom of the screen by toggling the "Vertical Panels" option in the main Firebug menu:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I found. But you have that arrow shows left/right. And your CSS console appears on the right side. My arrow shows up and down and CSS console appears under HTML console. How to make it appear to the right like in your image?

Comment: @Green There's an option in the main Firebug menu to toggle vertical panels. I've updated my answer to include this information for you.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same view of @Green where the properties/variable was show in bottom.

I tried the option **Vertical Panels** but not solved for me.

So I solved with **Reset Option** ☺ :-D

[image: Reset Option]